# PHP loop Foreach + While

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, fetch

I don't know why the result is return duplicate rows.
This code is try to fetching every coloumn & row data.

```
$n=array();
$s=array();
```

i declared array for moving data coloumn to variable

```
$i =0;
$x =0;
$matkul = 0;
while ($matkul<$ttlrow){    
        //try to fecth all coloumns data every row.
            foreach($dom->find('td[style="text-align:left;"]') as $b) {
                $n[$x]=$b->plaintext;
                $x++;                    
            }
        //try to show the data before insert to Database
        $k_mk= $n[0];
        $n_mk= $n[1];
        echo $k_mk . ' | ';
        echo $n_mk. ' | ';
            //try to fecth all coloumns data every row.
            foreach($dom->find('td[style="text-align:center;"]') as $a) {
                $s[$i]=$a->plaintext;
                $i++;
            }
        //try to show the data before insert to Database
        $sks= $s[0];
        $grd = $s[1];
        $bbt = $s[2];
        $nl = $s[3];
        $uid = $uid;
        echo $sks . ' | ';
        echo $grd. ' | ';
        echo $nl. '<br>';
        /*
       $sql = "INSERT INTO fokusipk_ks.jadwal (`uid`, `kd_mk`, `kd_sms`,  
       `nm_mk`, `nm_dsn`, `kd_kls`, `hari`, `jam`) 

       VALUES ('$uid', '$mk', '$sms', '$nmk', '$nmd', '$kls', '$hari', 
       '$jam');";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                #echo '.';
            }
        */
        $matkul++;
       //refresh the value to re-start fetching from the first coloumn
        $i=0;
        $x=0;
}


Code   | Courses                       | W | G | V

the results something like this:

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8

TPLB02 | PENGANTAR TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI | 2 | A | 8
```

Comment: I believe that the `foreach` loops should be outside the main loop since they're not depends on `$matkul`. It's like you have a loop that always harvesting the same page but printing only the first element.

Comment: how is $dom->find going to get a different result on each iteration of the while loop?

Comment: Thank you, it work. and more light weight.

Comment: May I write it as an answer and you'd approve it?

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 2 `foreach loops` of `$dom->find` are being located in a single `while loop` you're basically iterating over all the DOM elements that answers your criteria (`td[...]`). Those loops have no dependency in the while's loop so I would say it's not efficient.

Moreover, you're using constant keys for the `$s`,`$n` results so you'd always get the same results.

In order to have a better performance and working solution, you should put those 2 foreach loops outside (and above) the `while` loop. So the `$s` and `$n` arrays would contain all the desired elements and in your main loop just set a counter and increase it.

Keep in mind that in order to get 2 following element, you should do something like: `$s[$i]`, `$s[$i+1]`.

Make sure you check that the `$i` and `$i+1` are in the range of the array's limits.